# Div with Canvas in WebKit scrolls backwards

Tags: webkit

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but so far I've found nothing that makes any sense with this. I have a scrollable div with a canvas inside of it. In FF and IE all works as expected: Using drag scrolling with the mouse, the div scrolls normally. In WebKit, however, things are flipped. If I scroll up, the content moves down, if I scroll down, it moves up. If I scroll with my mousewheel, everything moves in the right direction. It's only using mousedown on the scroll bar that's screwed up. NOTE: I am using a 3rd party library to generate the contents of the canvas, which is where all the inline styles are coming from.

My code is as follows:

```
#Palette {
  height: 420px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

---

```
<div id="Palette" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); cursor: move;">
    <canvas width="268" height="420" tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2; -webkit-user-select: none; cursor: move;">
    This text is displayed if your browser does not support the Canvas HTML element.</canvas>
    <div style="position: absolute; overflow: auto; width: 268px; height: 420px; z-index: 1;">
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; overflow: auto; width: 268px; height: 420px; z-index: 1;">
      <div style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 700px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently an issue with WebKit 36. It is solved in 37.